# Py2exe creates program that dosen't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I've used Py2exe on my program:

```
import time

start = time.clock()

def sortare( n ):
    return sorted(str(n))

def main():
    n = 99999
    while True:
        if sortare (2 * n) == sortare(3 * n) == sortare(4 * n) == sortare(5 * n) == sortare(6 * n):
            print (n)
            break
        n += 1
    print (time.clock() - start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=['C:\Users\Rares\workspace\Test\src\Test.py'])
```

I've installed python 2.7.6 and py2exe as 64-bit, since my machine is this way. I use
`python C:\Python27\Test\test.py py2exe` in Windows CMD.

I have a folder called distr in which my program went, but when I run the exe, nothing happens. Not even an error or a txt file.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you double-click the exe to run it?  It's possible it runs and exits so fast, you see nothing.  Did you try running the exe from the command line?

Comment: I did encounter some exe's that just open and close, but this algorithm, I'm using needs at least 1 second to work. even so , there is absolutely no graphical hint that the program has run. Also running it from the CMD, it just shows a blank row.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the shebang `#!` line in one of the 1st two lines of your script.

look here for further info: [What does the symbol "#!" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288855/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python)

edit: depending on the python version you use (verify by `python -V`), the shebang line would be something like this:

`#! /usr/local/bin/python2.7`

Comment: Isn't the shebang for UNIX ? I'm running windows and even if I use it it's still the same issue.

Comment: @user3232848 a newbie solution i found on the web and might help is to a `raw_input("Press<enter>")` at the end of your code. also try adding some more  print statements to your code in order to get a status of the code reading process.

Comment: @user3232848 also for the shebang you are right its for unix however your program might have  to run in other os'es too so its a good practice to include it. feel  free to ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "windows=" as the option in your setup.py (which is for creating windows GUI applications), you need to use "console=" to create a windows console application (which will print stuff to the console).

I changed your setup.py to be as follows and it worked for me:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=[{'script':'C:\Users\Rares\workspace\Test\src\Test.py'}])
```